# Is it correct to say, "That was a little disappointment for me."?

Tags: tense

That was a little disappointment for me.

Comment: Would you like to tell us what context it was written in? Telling us what you think it means might also help as that might affect whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, the context is very important. This could be correct in certain scenarios, but in most cases it would be ‘disappointing’ instead of ‘disappointment’.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that.  It's a little more poetic than the more straightforward "That was a little disappointing for me", treating disappointment as if it's an object you can have rather than a general emotional state, but it's not at all uncommon to phrase it that way.

Answer (score 0):

My mother died before I could visit her - that was a huge disappointment for me.

The cheese I bought tasted of mould - that was a little disappointment for me.

It is correct.